# Get recently added / updated users from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to fetch all the users from Azure Active Directory who are recently modified/added using Azure Active Directory Graph SDK.

Checked about [Differential Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-differential-query), but not sure which property to use with this and how to use a differential query with C# SDK.

Is there any other property available, which can be used to query the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To track recent changes in users you can use delta to get the required details.

To begin tracking changes , initiate a http request:

`GET /users/delta`

Then you can add query parameters using C#:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var delta = await graphClient.Users
    .Delta()
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

**Note** : The above code gets all the details of the user .

To get *only the changed details* for the user use the code below:

```
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider ); 
    var delta = await graphClient.Users 
    .Delta() 
    .Request() 
    .Header("Prefer","return=minimal") 
    .GetAsync();
```

**Reference :**
[Get Delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: Please refrain from asking for upvotes/accepts on answers. Unneeded. Plus, you're answering a question that's off-topic as written: no code shown, no specific issue, just a general requirement that needs much more detail.